# How to use a range for conditional formatting in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet that I would like to highlight cells that are equal to any of the values listed in range of cells on another sheet. How do I do this?

Sheet 1 contains values I want to highlight in green any cell that equals any value in Row A of sheet 2.

For example, column A is

```
Apples
Oranges
Peaches
```

I want to highlight any cell on sheet 1 that equals `Apples`, `Oranges`, or `Peaches`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2010 you can use cells from other sheets in the conditional formats formula.  In earlier versions this is not possible.

To search if the value is in a list use the `CountIF` function.

[image: Conditional Format Rule Dialog Box]

Comment: I don't want to count the number of occurrences. I have edited my question to make it more clear. (I hope)

Comment: Have you tried it?  The conditional format is asking a true false question.  Anything other than 0 is true.  If the count is greater than zero it will correctly highlight the cell

Comment: Yes and it said I had too few arguments. Can you break down what's in the parenthesis?

Comment: Here is what I have `=COUNTIF('Classes I Teach'!$A:$A,)` what do I put after the comma for the range?

Comment: The `CountIf` function needs two arguments.  ([Range to search in], [Value to Search]).  For you it looks you need to add the value you are searching for after the 'Classes I Teach'!$A:$A.  My advice, get the formula to work in an adjacent cell (not in the conditional format box) and then copy that formula to the conditional format

Comment: I tried adding the range and that didn't work either. It seems redundant because the conditional formatting already asks me for a range of cells to apply to.

Comment: This is what tried as well `=COUNTIF('Classes I Teach'!$A:$A,$1:$1048576)`

Comment: The range of cells to apply to is the cells that the conditional format can adjust the formatting to.  It doesn't mean they use those cells to evaluate whether or not to apply the conditional format.  Get the countif formula to work in an adjacent cell and then move it over to the conditonal format.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4432/discussion-between-larry-and-wbeard52)